# How to convert dot notation to string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I was looking for a way to convert something in dot notation into a string using Javascript. Basically here's what I am looking for:

```
function dotToString(dotNotation){
  return something;
}


dotToString(this.is.just.a.test);
// Would return "this.is.just.a.test"
```

Comment: that would throw an error.. unless that path is actually defined and you are not going to get the path to the property in an object.

Comment: if `this` or `this.is`  or `this.is.just` etc is `undefined` javascript will throw an error - otherwise `this.is.just.a.test` will result in something (an object or primitive) - and there's no concept of backtracking up to see how we got to this final object, as there could be multiple "parents") ... short answer, you can't

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem. What is the purpose for what you think you need this?

Comment: I am trying to create a node package that allows you to browse the file-system in dot notation. So, the end goal is for require(dn(src.script.js)) = require("src/script.js) with dn being a function;

Comment: Dot notation is used for accessing properties on objects.  You're trying to commandeer that notation for a purpose that the javascript parser doesn't support.  This isn't going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: When javascript passes an argument to a function, it passes in the value from the variable you are attempting to pass in. At no point does the `dotToString` function see `this.is.just.a.test` (It would see "blah", if `this.is.just.a.test = "blah"`). This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with proxies.

```js
function makeDotProxy(name) {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (prop === 'valueOf' || prop === 'toString') return () => name;
      if (typeof prop === 'symbol') return Reflect.get(target, prop);
      return makeDotProxy(name + '.' + prop);
    }
  });
}

const This = makeDotProxy('this');
console.log(This.is.a.just.a.test.toString());
```

But then, why would you want to?

Comment: Doesn't this require the object itself to be a proxy? This doesn't just work for all objects out of the box.

Comment: It cannot be two things at once. It can either be a regular object, which works like a regular object, or a special object, implemented here using a proxy, which returns the dot path, but not both.